# Obtener datos inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

me encuentro con un inconveniente, tengo una tabla pots, una tabla comentarios y una tabla users, nececito sacar en una sola consulta el nombre del usuario propietario del post , el nombre de los usuarios que comentan los posts, resulta que el lio que tengo es en una consulta sacar 2 veces de a misma tabla 2 nombres diferentes, y la clausula con la cual busco es el id del post, tengo esta consulta y me trae los datos me falta sacar el nombre los que comentan, pero la consulta me entrega el id del propietario de ese comentario, la estructura de la bd es:
users=id,nombre
posts=id,titulo,descripcion,user_id que es llave foranea de users.id
comentarios=id,comentario,id_post llave foranea de post.id, id_user llave foranea de users.id

la sentencia que ejecuto es la siguiente:

```
select * from users inner join posts on posts.user_id= users.id inner join comentarios on comentarios.post_id=posts.id where posts.id=413
```

me trae todos los datos bien me trae el propietario del post y me trae los campos de la tabla comentarios tambien bien, solo que me trae los campos con id_user,_id_post  y nececito ahora obtener tambien el nombre de ese id_users que se genera en la tabla comentarios ya que el es el propietario del comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si te entiendo adecuadamente, pero si lo que necesitas es solamente los nombre de los usuarios del post y los comments, entiendo que algún así debería ser:

```
Select posts_user.nombre PostUser, comments_user.nombre CommentUser
from   posts
       left join users posts_user    on posts.user_id = posts_user.id
       left join comments            on posts.id = comments.id_post
       left join users comments_user on comments.user_id = comments_user.id
where. post.id = 413
```

Eso te va a devolver una fila por cada autor de comment, con el nombre del autor del post y el autor del comment.

Algo así:

```
PostUser   CommentUser
Pablo      Julián
Pablo      Alberto
Pablo      Ernesto
```

Eso quiere decir que el Post lo escribió Pablo, y tiene comentarios de Julián, Alberto y Ernesto.

Comment: El inconveniente es que solo hay una tabla users la cual tiene el nombre de los usuarios las otras 2 tienen es ids

Comment: La solución de Pablo es perfecta para responder a tu pregunta. El tema es, Camilo34, ya si quieres que para un post quieras 3 líneas de resultado, si quieres o no los ids de post y/o usuarios, etc. Si por ejemplo quisieras todos los usuarios con comentarios concatenados, sería algo como `,GROUP_CONCAT(comments_user.nombre) CommentUsers FROM .... WHERE ... GROUP BY posts.id`

Comment: Gracias VFG!. Camilo, lo que estoy haciendo en el select es hacer 2 joins contra la tabla de usuarios, uno con alias post_user (le decís de acá en adelante a esta tabla llámala de esta forma) y el otro con alias comments_user. Probaste ejecutarlo el SQL?

Comment: Hola amigos muchas gracias por sus respuestas , si lo probe pero estoy enredado  post_user.nombre as postUser   iria ese as? Ahi lo que no comprendo es de donde sale posts_user.nombre sobre todo el posts_user, les agradezco mucho por sus valiosos aportes , debe estar bueno lo que em explican, solo que no logro replicar lo que me muestran contra mi query, disculpas y mil gracias

Comment: La llevo asi pero no logro comprender mi tabla users tiene el atributo name en vez de nombre, error mio, consumo la consulta asi, pero no me funciona:


Select posts_user.name as PostUser, comentarios_user.name as CommentUser
from   posts
       left join users posts_user    on posts.user_id = posts_user.id
       left join comentarios            on posts.id = comentarios.id_post
       left join users comments_user on comentarios.user_id = comments_user.id 
       where posts.id = 4

Comment: Voy punto por punto, el tema del posts_user es un alias, le indicas a SQL que a esa tabla la vas a llamar de ahora en adelante con ese alias. Es decir, cada vez que digas posts_users estas mencionando la tabla users. El "as" es opcional, lo podes poner o no. Si no recuerdo mal el ANSI SQL no lo lleva y por eso yo no lo uso.

Comment: Tema Alias, para que se usan? En general para hacer más legibles los queries, pero hay una situación donde si o si lo tenes que usar y es esta. Si vas a usar 2 veces la misma tabla, cómo le decís al SQL cuando queres usar una tabla y cuando otra? Lo haces mediante un alias. En este ejemplo use 2 veces la tabla users, la primera le puse de alias posts_users (porque es el usuario del post) y la segunda comments_users (porque es el usuario del comment). De esta forma es como si fueran dos tablas, pero con los datos de la misma.